# Terraform still trying to resolve interpolation in resource with count of zero

Tags: dns, terraform

I am trying to create PTR records for a server deployment. The server(s) below need to be deployed after a dependent set of servers are applied so we currently do this by running one apply deploying those server modules then a second deploy where we change these resources counts from 0 to however many we're looking to deploy. I've added a new resource to create a PTR record for these servers and even with the count set to 0 Terraform attempts to resolve the interpolation. It doesn't do this for the A record resource just the PTR record resouce.

Here is the code, I even hard coded the count to 0 to see if there was an issue with the variable. The list is expected to be empty while the count is at 0. I expect that Terraform wouldn't try to resolve the interpolation.

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "ds_sync_A_records" {
  // same number of records as instances
  provider = "aws.dns"
  count = 0
  // count = "${var.ping_sync_cluster_count}"
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.zone_company_io.zone_id}"
  name = "ping-sync-0${count.index}.${var.domain_name}"
  type = "A"
  ttl = "10"
  // matches up record N to instance N
  records = ["${element(module.ping_sync_hot_server.private_server_ips, count.index)}"]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "ds_sync_PTR_records" {
  // same number of records as instances
  provider = "aws.dns"
  count = 0
  // count = "${var.ping_sync_cluster_count}"
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.zone_company_io.zone_id}"
  name = "${format(
    "%s.%s.%s.$s.in-appr.arpa",
    element(split(".", element(module.ping_sync_hot_server.private_server_ips, count.index)), 3), 
    element(split(".", element(module.ping_sync_hot_server.private_server_ips, count.index)), 2),
    element(split(".", element(module.ping_sync_hot_server.private_server_ips, count.index)), 1), 
    element(split(".", element(module.ping_sync_hot_server.private_server_ips, count.index)), 0) 
  )}"
  type = "PTR"
  ttl = "10"
  // matches up record N to instance N
  records = ["${element(module.ping_sync_hot_server.private_server_ips, count.index)}"]
}
```

Error message on apply:

```
Error running plan: 3 error(s) occurred:

* element: element() may not be used with an empty list in:

${element(module.ping_sync_hot_server.private_server_ips, count.index)}
* element: element() may not be used with an empty list in:

${element(module.ping_sync_hot_server.private_server_ips, count.index)}
* element: element() may not be used with an empty list in:

${element(module.ping_sync_hot_server.private_server_ips, count.index)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use splat syntax (`*`) when returned record is a list.

```
records = [
  "${element(module.ping_sync_hot_server.*.private_server_ips, count.index)}",
]
```